# Change Apache's document root dynamically - simple A/B testing solution

Tags: php, apache, nginx, load-balancing, ab-testing

I want to implement simplest possible split testing (A/B). 
Currently I have something like this

```
/public_web
  index.php    # this selects random version and redirects with all GET params 
    /A
      /vendor
      /web/
        /index.php
    /B
      /web/
        /index.php
    /C
      /web/
        /index.php
```

I want to be able to just copy a directory with all files to create another version for testing.

Currently it's working fine with few exception - the URLs and security.

The document root normally would be /A/web so public url is i.e. www.site.com, but in order to run split tests like I want to, I need to put document root to /public/web so the url of the site is actually www.site.com/A/web ( and /B/web and C/web etc )

So I'm looking for a way to change Apache's document root ( or it can be nginx )
dynamically. Is that possible? 
Can I write simple script to make choices which folder should be document root for each session?

I have a gut feel that it's not possible because it would need to keep session, but maybe some sort of load balancer software that keeps session can do it?

The A/B script is ultra simple select random version from list of available directories and use it as document root.

I know that there are other ways of running split testing, but I'm just interested if it's possible do it like stated above.

Many thanks